# How to convert string to hashtable in 1 go?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

This is strictly a learning experience:

I have a .CSV file that I'm using to define my deployment environments. One of the variables has to be in a Hash Table format.

Can anyone come up with a clever way to put it all in one line?
Right now I harvest them as a string from CSV, conver to array, convert array to hash table.

Simplified code:

```
Foreach($i in $DefaultCSV){...
$App_Fabric_Hosts_a = $i.App_Fabric_Hosts.split(",")} 


$App_Fabric_Hosts_h = @{}
foreach($r in $App_Fabric_Hosts_a){$App_Fabric_Hosts_h.add($r,"22233")}
```

Comment: Why do you care that it's a one-liner?

Comment: (A function call = "one line" ;-)

Comment: You perhaps can give an example of te csv you have and what you want to get in a hashtable.

Comment: I dont have to, this is strictly a learning experience. It seems that it COULD be done, but I cant figure out how to populate via foreach loop and parse in one line.

Comment: @JPBlanc
CSV file example is simple:
Line 1: Environment; header2; header3; header4; etc......
Line 2: Test; value2;valueA,valueB,ValueC,ValueD,ValueE;Value4
Line 3: Dev; value2;valueA,valueB,ValueC,ValueD,ValueE;Value4

So, different values go into different places. Some go into web.config, others go into app config, etc..

For example, Value 2 is consumed as a string, Value 3 as a hash table, Value 4 as array.

I can parse value4 into array easily using .split(",")
But I cant parse value 3 into hash table without using 2 separate commands.

Comment: I think the core of the issue is that I dont know how to declare a hash table and populate it in one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I came up with:

```
$d=@{};foreach($r in $DefaultCSV[$arrayposition].app_fabric_hosts.split(",")){$d.add($r,"22233")}
```